# Copy a cell with formatting as literal text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A little tricky to explain, but basically, my cells are formatted as shortened dollar values with "K", "M", "B". So for example, $1,500,000 is shown as $1.5M, or $830,000 as $830.0K.

Now I want to copy the exact format of that cell "literally", meaning that I will not be copying just the formatting, but rather "treat" the cell as is.

Example:

> B2 = 1500000 (in formula bar)
>
> Formatting: `Custom| [>=1000000000]$#,##0.0,,," B";[>=1000000]$#0.0,," M";$#0.0," K"`
>
> Shown in the cell as: $1.5M

Once I do the "literal" copy to C2, it should look like this:

> C2 = $1.5M (in formula bar)
>
> Formatting: General
>
> Show in the cell as : $1.5M

The reason - I'm doing a previous month comparison and will need to add a character after the cell that will be used as a "symbol" in InDesign, specifically Wingdings 3 with "p" & "q" as Up/Down arrows. I have a simple If statement that compares last month's data, and simply adds the character in:
`=if(B2>D2, C2 & "p", C2 & "q")` (let's treat that C2 is the formatted $1.5M)

But using that formula, it removes the formatting entirely and so, the shortened format is gone. It will only show the value as "***1500000 p***", when the "desired output should be "***$1.5M p***". And you can't really apply any more formatting after that, since adding a character means that Excel now treats the value as Text, and not a number that can easily be formatted.

Is there a way to have the best of both worlds, having both the shortened dollar values and have a character at the end when doing comparisons? If

I'd rather stay away from VBA, but if it's the only way to do so, then might as well use it instead of not having anything at all.

Comment: Have you tried using `TEXT`? Note - you can add up and down arrows with conditional formatting.

Comment: @BigBen can you explain more about using TEXT? I was able to do the conditional formatting one that looks like what I want, but once I begin moving the cells onto the file that InDesign is linked to, the conditional formatting disappears, leaving it without the up/down arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with BigBen's comment. I think Text is the only way non VBA. 
Maybe a helper column with this formula?

```
=IF(A1>=1000000000,TEXT(A1,"$#0.0,,,")&" B",IF(A1>=1000000,TEXT(A1,"$#0.0,,")&" M",TEXT(A1,"$#0.0,")&" K"))
```